# I am confused in building query for laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using folloing table structure

```
resource_types 
      id
      type

communiction_links
      id
      inst_id
      rety_id
      cont_id
      value

 contacts
      id
      fname
      lname
      image
      park
```

I want to search the pattern in two tables and retrive data from two tables.
if pattern is digit then i will search in communication_links and if pattern is alphabates then i will search in contact in fname or lname column (where communication_links's cont_id and contact's id should be same) and (communication_links's rety_id and resource_type's id should be same)

i wrote down following query but i got error.

```
$parent_contact = \App\Contact::join('communication_links','contacts.id','=','communication_links.cont_id')
                                            >join('resource_types','resource_types.id','=','communication_links.rety_id')
                                            ->select('contacts.id','contacts.image','contacts.fname','contacts.lname','communication_links.value')
                                            ->where('resource_types.type','LIKE',"{mobile}%")
                                            ->where(function ($query) {
                                                $query->where('communication_links.value','LIKE',"{$request->search_string}%")
                                                        ->orWhere('contacts.fname','LIKE',"{$request->search_string}%")
                                                        ->orWhere('contacts.lname','LIKE',"{$request->search_string}%");
                                            })
                                            ->get();
```

Comment: What was the error???

Comment: ErrorException in fetchDataController.php line 50:
Undefined variable: request

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because `$request` doesn't exist in the scope of the closure. Whenever you have a closure and you want to use a variable that exists outside of it you have to pass it to the closure using `use`.

change:

```
->where(function ($query) {
```

to

```
->where(function ($query) use($request) {
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now i got "contact not found"  but contact is there. is there any error in maintaining the relatioship between tables?

Comment: Are all your tables names correct e.g. is the contact table `contact` or `contacts`? Also, if you go back to your other question where you have a similar query I can try and help you with that and save you creating multiple questions around the issue.

Comment: Ok, in that case can you copy the error and put it into your question?